# Django: Get previous value in clean() method

Tags: python, django

I have a model `CustomModel` with an IntegerField.

```
class CustomModel(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

When I create a new instance of `CustomModel` in the admin, I have to do validation, so I use the `clean` method and have access to the value with.

```
def clean(self):
    value = self.count
    ...
```

My problem:

When I change the instance of CustomModel, I only have access to the new, changed value but not to the original value. However, for my validation I have to compare the new value and the value before the instance got edited.

I could not found a solution how to get access. Does somebody know?

Comment: Where is this `clean` method? If it's on the form, you can look at `self.instance.count`.

Comment: No, the `clean` method is in my models.py (it's an method of CustomModel).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not take advantage of a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)? Form data is saved in two steps:

1. To the form instance
2. To the model instance

So when you have a form:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomModel
        fields = ['count']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        count = cleaned_data.get('count')

        if count < self.instance.count:
            self.add_error('count', 'You cannot decrease the counter')

        return cleanded_data
```

You can then [override the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) within the `django` admin site.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a solution just using the model:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.pk:
        previous_count = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk).count
    else:
        previous_count = None       # If saving a new instance
```

`self.__class__` access the model class and fetch the currently stored `.count` value.